# Converting dynamic data to hex in array

Tags: python, arrays, list, smartcard, pyscard

I am working on a smartcard in python and using pyscard library. I have the following data:

> WRITE_PREF = [0X80, 0X12, 0X00, 0X01, 0X12, 0X01, 0X00, 0X00, 0X20,
> 0X00, 0X00, 0X00]

I am receiving random data(of length 10) in string format. After conversion to hex, I get the array with hex values of the random string data.

Problem:
The array of hex values has the values in string form.

> Example: ['0x33','0x32'....]

When I append WRITE_PREF and this hex data, I get the array like this:

> [128, 18, 0, 1, 18, 1, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, '0x33', '0x32']

I convert the first part to hex and replace the array values of integer with the hex ones.
When I transmit data using the command:

```
 card.connection.transmit(final_array_in_hex)
```

I get error. I am pretty sure it is because the values in array are hex strings. If I transmit some data manually like:

> [0x33,0x32,0x30]

It is working fine. So the problem must be because of the quotes in array data. Example:

> ['0x33','0x32','0x30']

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `[int(x, 16) for x in foobar]`?

Comment: @ggorlen that will convert it to decimal value. I just want the values without quotes. Using your solution will result in an array with the decimal equivalent of the hex values

Comment: Decimal and hex values are the same underlying numbers. To Python, it's all integers. `0x33` and `51` are the same thing. Type `0x33` into a Python interpreter and you get 51. Either you have a string or an integer here; "values without quotes" is identical to "decimal equivalent of the hex values".

Comment: @Shubh9718 try it: `result = 0x20 == 32`. Both are the same number, and it’s stored neither as hex nor as decimal, but as binary inside the computer memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python dictionary automatically converting hexadecimals into decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289209/python-dictionary-automatically-converting-hexadecimals-into-decimals)

Comment: @ggorlen thank you it worked. I used the decimal values only as you mentioned and the smartcard works just as fine.

Comment: Thank you @KonradRudolph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `str` representing a hexadecimal number, let's turn that into an `int`.  We save space using `int`, also `int` is flexible.  We can choose how to represent this `int`.

```
s = ['0x33','0x32']
s = [int(_s, base=16) for _s in s]
print(s) # defaults to displaying an int as decimal
print(list(f'0x{_s:x}' for _s in s)) # specify that we want to display as `x` or hexamdecimal
```

Output:

```
[51, 50]
['0x33', '0x32']
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the edit is right, but I do get correct data when passing it as an integer. So thank you for the answer everyone. Guess I should do more study to the core side of python.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair enough, I pruned my answer.